# Javascript Regex replace for 0.00 decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a current regex but there's no decimal allowed, it only allows numbers.

```
val.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

What I need to achieve is, there's an input with 0.00 default value. For example I will input 549075

The sequence must be:
0.05
0.54
5.49
54.90
549.07
5,490.75

Is this possible to regex replace every I input data?

Comment: Are you willing to put in leading zeros?

Comment: yes, for example if i need to input 500.00. My input will be 50000 on numpad.

Comment: What will 0004 become?

Comment: @Thefourthbird 0.04 still.

Comment: @keisaac That's trailing, not leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```js
    let input = 123455;
    let currentVal = input/100;
    let result = [];
    while(currentVal !== 0) {
        result.push(currentVal);
        currentVal = Math.floor(currentVal*10)/100;
    }

    console.log(result);
```